# Relation between the Casimir energy and the central charge in CFT in general

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime, quantum-anomalies, casimir-effect

In 2d CFT we know that the Casimir energy of the vacuum is proportional to the conformal central charge $c$.
$$
F_L=f_0 L-\frac{\pi c}{6 L} \tag{1}
$$
where $F$ is the free energy and L is the circumference of the 2d cylinder. However is we search the Wikipedia we find the Casimir energy is due to the quantum fluctuation of the field, the zero-point energy. To me, the conformal anomaly and zero-point energy are two different concepts, and usually people won't relate these two concepts. I'm wondering whether the conformal anomaly and quantum fluctuation can be related or are the Casimir energy in these two contexts the same thing? Can the Casimir energy be related to the conformal anomaly dimension other than 2?

Comment: [c is for casimir](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string.pdf#page=92).